Parameter \"obj\" to Document() must be an object, got \"\" (type string)
I have a problem, in Postman, the result of the request is this:

This is my Model:
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const mongoosePaginate = require("mongoose-paginate-v2");

const ComentariosSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    creator: String,
    comentario: String,
    created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    raiting: Number
});

const SoporteSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    folio: {
        type: Number,
        unique: true
    },
    documentos: String,
    servicio: String,
    descripcion: String,
    dueno: String,
    asignado: String,
    estado: String,
    prioridad: String,
    created_at: Date,
    MotivoCancel: String,
    CancelDate: Date,
    Cancelby: String,
    AsignDate: Date,
    comentarios: [ComentariosSchema]
});

SoporteSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Soporte", SoporteSchema);

This is my Controller:
const Soporte = require("../models/soporte");
async function addComnentarios(req, res) {
    try {
        const soporteId = req.params.id;
        const comentario = req.body;
        console.log("Comentario: ", comentario);
        if (!comentario || typeof comentario !== 'object' || Array.isArray(comentario)) {
            return res.status(400).send({ msg: "Comentario inválido" });
        }
        console.log("Req.body", req.body);
        const soporte = await Soporte.findById(soporteId);
        console.log(soporte);
        if (!soporte) {
            return res.status(404).send({ msg: "Ticket no encontrado" });
        }
        soporte.comentarios.push(comentario);
        const comentarioUpdated = await soporte.save();
        console.log(comentarioUpdated);
        res.status(200).send({ msg: "Comentario creado", comentarioUpdated });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send({ msg: "Error al crear el comentario", error });
    }
}

This should save the information. I compared with other answers and solutions, but the only result is the same error. Can you help me please?

you haven't shown the request you make - nor the output of console.log("Comentario: ", comentario); which would help greatly in telling you what you're doing wrong

Share comentario. It is not passing the validation checks of await soporte.save().

You need to use the new keyword as well when creating schemas so new mongoose.Schema({...}).

Hi, What is your Mongoose version ? As we can see similar issues have been discussed with the Mongoose team sometime in 2019, it may be possible that it would have been fixed by now. For instance, you may please see the discussions : https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/7242, https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8086. I could also reproduce the issue, but not at the push statement, but at creating the parent document. However your case is little different as it happens at push.
